# How to get Node Js Hello World app to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

### EDIT

Okay it has magically started working all of a sudden. Never mind guys. You can ignore the question.

---

## EDIT 2

I see why. I didn't realize that after typing node hello_world_app.js I had to leave that running. I was typing `CNTRL + C` to get the shell back. You would think a tutorial would mention that. Oh well "the more you know (rainbow cut)".

---

I am trying to follow a node tutorial. So far the install went smoothly. I'm up to the part where I make a hello world script but I have become stuck.

This is the hello world app created:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000, '192.168.163.129');

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://192.168.163.129:8000/");
```

In the tutorial they are pointing the ip to localhost but I am working on an external machine (hosted on my laptop but inside vmware) so I entered the internal IP I'm using to access it:

```
192.168.163.129
```

That's the IP I use to successflly ssh into that machine. But it's not working. When I go to:

```
http://192.168.163.129:8000
```

I get server not found error.

How to get this to work?

I should also mention when I enter the command:

```
node hello_world_app.js
```

I get this response:

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Even though in the script I specify a different IP.

Comment: May seems stupid, are you sure you can serve from the ip you specified? (may also try `0.0.0.0` to serve as a wildcard)

Comment: @Jashwant I can only vote to delete. But I won't since I can see others having the same issue their first time and finding this useful.

Comment: hmm... but please remove `Okay it has magically started working all of a sudden. Never mind guys. You can ignore the question.
`. Its giving me a wrong impression and I didnt look into your second edit.